# nginx not using configured dir for modules

Tags: nginx

If I build nginx from source (version 1.18) it does not seem to use the configured directory to find the modules. I run configure with `--modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules` and that is shown when I run -V on the binary produced from the build. But when I start nginx it fails with

```
2024/02/02 13:00:59 [emerg] 1961284#1961284: dlopen() "/usr/modules/ndk_http_module.so" failed (/usr/modules/ndk_http_module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/10-mod-http-ndk.conf:1
```

It looks in `/usr/modules`. This happens for every module in modules-enabled. The modules are in `/usr/lib/nginx/modules` and if I put the full path in the files in modules-enabled it works.

This does not happen if I use nginx from the debian package from the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: This forum is for programming questions and not server management. Either way, compiling software is discouraged on a production server. [Use packages wherever possible.](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/where-compilation-went-wrong)

Comment: If I could use a package I would, but I can't. I'd post the reasons why, but according to you this is not the correct forum for that. But yet, there are 16.3k watchers of the nginx tag, and 55.2k questions.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the issue was. `--modules-path` does not set where it looks for modules and I have to set it with `--prefix`.